# SKScene being called twice when I add an iAd banner to ViewController

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I found out that my Main menu Scene is being called twice when I have a iad banner in my viewcontroller. Does anyone know why it is acting this way?

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];



}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

in viewcontroller.h

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>{
```

I think they may be a problem with the UIView because I heard UIViews don't work well with Sprite-Kit

Comment: can you show your codes?

Comment: have you tried to call with notification?

Comment: Right now the ads that come up when you run with the simulator don't even show up. But no I haven't tried to call with notification

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure may be this work.

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"hideAd" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];
}


- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"hideAd"]) {
        [banner setAlpha:0];
    }else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
        [banner setAlpha:1];
    }
}
```

Call with this in your scene where you want

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil];
```

Comment: this is a good idea. My problem is though that regardless if the banner is hidden or not it loads my SKScene twice. Have any ideas?